# Report even or odd number in JS

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to do the following exercise:
Create a function that takes an integer as an argument and returns "Even" for even numbers or "Odd" for odd numbers.

Here is my code; I can't figure out what I'm missing:

```
function even_or_odd(n) {
  if(n % 2 === 0)
  {
    console.log('Even');
  } else {
    console.log('Odd');
  }
};
```

Comment: What is it that you're expecting?  The function looks correct to me...

Comment: Do you need to do any error checking -- like validating that the argument is an integer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not returning anything, just outputing it in the console.

```
function even_or_odd(n) {
    if(n % 2 === 0) {
      return 'Even';
    } else {
      return 'Odd';
    }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming "i" is the number to check...

```
if(i%2){alert('odd');} else {alert('even');}
```

Answer (score 0):

Nothing just return the string if returning is the goal:

```js
    function even_or_odd(n) {
      if (n % 2 === 0) {
        return 'Even';
      } else {
        return 'Odd';
      }
    };
    
    alert(even_or_odd(5));
    alert(even_or_odd(2));
```

Answer (score 0):

If anybody looking for shorthand using es6, They can try this-

```js
const evenOrOdd = number => number % 2 ? 'Odd' : 'Even';

// Outputs-
evenOrOdd(2) // Even
evenOrOdd(3) // Odd
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function evenOrOdd(number) {
  return number % 2 === 1 ? `Odd` : `Even`;
}

console.log(evenOrOdd(8));
```

Comment: What does that add to the already provided answers?

Answer (score -3):

*yeha I was having the same problem,then i remembered i need to return the values*

```
function even_or_odd(number) {
      if(number % 2 == 0){
        return "Even";
      }else{
        return "Odd";
      }
}
```

Comment: remove "()" after return, like: return "Even"

Comment: ohh, my bad. thank you for the clarification